# Image upload query in database

Tags: php

I am using the following sql query to upload a image into the database...

```
$query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date')    VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
 mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());
```

But getting and error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('images/25-10-201' at line 1
```

Can any body help me to fix the bug?

Answer (score 0):

Tables in mysql are escaped with backticks, not quotes. So use this instead:

```
$query_upload="INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`,`submission_date`)    VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

See also [Should I use backticks or not when escaping keywords in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952677/should-i-use-backticks-or-not-when-escaping-keywords-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query_upload="INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`,`submission_date`)    VALUES ('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
```

table and columns names surrounded by backticks ` not single qoute '